# php console log speed

Tags: date-time, errors

How do I log speed benchmarks to a console in php? I don't want to `echo` the results for the user to see, but just in some kind of log.

I know that I can get the time elapsed with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850259/calculate-elapsed-time-in-php):

```
$first  = new DateTime( '11:35:20' );
$second = new DateTime( '12:00:45' );

$diff = $first->diff( $second );

echo $diff->format( '%H:%I:%S' ); // -> 00:25:25
```

but I want to log the time, and not `echo` it. Do I use the error_log?

Comment: I think Stackoverflow would be more appropriate than WPSE, for such pure PHP questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you will write inside the console of your browser, then use one of a lot of helpers or use a small custom function in php. The follow function is easy to use and  log inside the console of the browser.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'debug_to_console' ) ) {
    /**
     * Simple helper to debug to the console
     * 
     * @param  object, array, string $data
     * @return string
     */
    function debug_to_console( $data ) {

        $output = '';
        $output .= 'console.info( \'Debug in Console:\' );';
        $output .= 'console.log(' . json_encode( $data ) . ');';

        echo '<script>' . $output . '</script>';
    }
}
```

A image say more:
[image]

Alternative use a library, like [ChromePHP](http://www.chromephp.com/) for Chromium Project, [Webug](https://github.com/fedosov/webug/) for many different browsers or [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) as example. Is give a lot more helpers in this topic.

If you will work this inside WordPress, then is a fast a easy to use helper the plugin [Debug Objects](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects), this plugin have the source from the easy to use funtione above inside the plugin and also the CromePHP library.